# how to install and run bootstrap on bluefish?

Tags: ide, html5, css, bluefish

in windows we simply paste the three folders css, js , fonts in the webmatrix . i am using bluefish IDE , what's the procedure to download and run bootstrap in bluefish ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just downloaded and extracted the bootstrap zip file and extracted it into a test website and certainly this is all that is required to run the files with Bluefish:

[image]

You will have to link the css, scripts and fonts into your project manually though...